# NHibernate not loading one to many children

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Yo

i have the following nhibernate class:

```
public class User
{

    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string FullName { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<RatingItem> RatingItems { get; set; }


    public User()
    {
        RatingItems = new List<RatingItem>();

    }

    public virtual void AddRatingItems(RatingItem ratingItem)
    {
        ratingItem.User = this;
        RatingItems.Add(ratingItem);
    }
}
```

and the following fluent mapping:

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap() {
        Id(x=>x.Id);
        Map(x=>x.FullName);
        HasMany(x=> x.RatingItems).Inverse().Cascade.All();

    }
}
```

rating item has similar except it sees the user object like this:

```
public virtual User User { get; set; }
```

and the mapping file has this:

```
References(x => x.User);
```

however - when i try to load a user object and get then ask for its RatingItems - i get the following error:

could not initialize a collection: [IsItGd.Model.Entities.User.RatingItems#1]

anyone?

:)

w://

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was due to the foreign key naming convention - i added a new convention to use my naming scheme and it worked great.

w://